# barplot - frequency should be based on a pattern in column and ratio (x axis)

Tags: r

let me quickly explain the problem. picture a dataset like this

```
data<- data.frame("Amino.acid" = c("TRPPS;PNSTED", "ERDDS", "PSRND", "SDEEN", "GSRTN"), 
                   "log2.ratio"=c(2.4,0,-1,-2,-1))
```

In real my list is much longer lets say 12000 rows. What i really wanna do is to get the frequency for a specific amino acid  pattern, and then plot the density vs the log2ratio. So for example the Pattern R-X-X-S should be detected in the amino acid column AND sometimes the sequence is separated by a ";" and the pattern analysis should be done for both.

I can just think about something ugly like gsub and subset function for a lots of log2 ratios but there should be an elegant solution. (maybe with the density function??)

In the end I would like to get a plot for density (y) vs log2raito (x) for a specific pattern AND for all other but this specific amino acid sequence pattern.

Comment: You should be looking in the Bioconductor packages for functions that support sequence analysis with wildcards. As stated, however, you seem to be expecting more than is reasonable. You are not defining what is meant by "separated" in reference to ";" , nor are you defining what sort of "density" you might want, all this while leaving the search space wide open.

Comment: thx, with separated i mean that it happens that there are two sequence entries in one row. These sequences are separated by ";".

Comment: density i mean the percentage of the frequencie in a specific interval of the ratio. http://www.pnas.org/content/105/31/10762.full maybe this graph helps. but insteady of frequencie i would like to plot the density (frequencies in the specific ratio interval devided by total no. of entries for the specific pattern) im sry

Comment: Notice that those investigators prespecified particular motifs, thus constraining their search space to a manageable dimension. You have not offered any guidance in that direction so I continue to think you are expecting the program to think for you ... and that is unreasonable..

Comment: actually i also did by saying specific pattern for example "R-X-X-S" where X is any amino acid should be detected in the sequence window, what's actually an example from the paper. Im sorry for being  unspecific in the definition of my question.

Comment: The way it was written it sounded (to me anyway) as though the program should find every possible pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have an aversion to naming dataframes "data" so instead named it "pdat":

```
 barplot( table(pdat[ grep("R[A-Z]{2}S", pdat$Amino.acid), "log2.ratio"] ))
```

That's about as specific as I can get with that tiny dataset. The grepping pattern would not register with "AARP;SNORE":

```
> grep("R[A-Z]{2}S","AARP;SNORE")
integer(0)
```

This is the plot for the complementary rows (just as a minus sign):

```
barplot( table(pdat[ -grep("R[A-Z]{2}S", pdat$Amino.acid), "log2.ratio"] ))
```

It's not a density, so reaching for hte density function will doom your efforts.

Comment: thx a lot! i actually had this code but i didnt know how to set the 2 unspecific amino acids e.g. {2} tx